# PyDev Package Explorer doesn't retain directories expanded states between sessions

Tags: pydev, eclipse-neon

For Eclipse Neon 4.6.1 and PyDev 5.3.1.201610311318 (i.e. everything fully updated as of today).

Is there a way to help *PyDev Package Explorer* remember the state of expanded directories between sessions?

- This problem began only after I upgraded to Neon. Eclipse Mars and PyDev retained folder states between sessions.
- My PyDev project contains a nested directories structure. No level is deeper than four levels below the project's root.
- I expand one or another portions of that dirs structure as I work. After I close and restart Eclipse, all the project directories and files are present and accessible but the Package Explorer hasn't retained the dirs' expanded state from the previous session.
- Sometimes some dirs may be expanded to two of four levels, but sometimes not at all.
- Eclipse Neon remembers all other view settings. The size of the Eclipse window, the workspace's tools, and the files that were open in the editor are all where they were at the end of the preceding session.

Not sure it's pertinent, but because Eclipse Neon implements a different projects structure than preceding versions, when I upgraded from Mars to Neon I made a full copy of my Mars project (in case I needed to revert), then pointed Neon to that copy. I then archived my Mars project so that I'm certain I'm not accidentally accessing two different Python projects.

When I created the copy of the project might I have left something behind that affects the PyDev Package Explorer's ability to remember project directory settings between sessions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I've fixed my own problem.

As mentioned, the problem arose after I upgraded from Eclipse Mars to Eclipse Neon. As part of doing that I tried to re-use my Mars-level projects. When I did, Neon told me it needed to "upgrade" those projects to the newer Neon format. But that process evidently brings a lot of problems along with it.

So I did the following:

1. I of course had all my Mars projects' source files backed up.
2. I completely deleted my new Neon installation and reinstalled from scratch: No Mars projects, no inherited settings, no anything else.
3. In Eclipse Neon, I created new, empty projects (Python, Java, and Java EE).
4. I copied ONLY my Mars projects' source files -- and nothing else -- into the clean Neon installation's new project directories.

Because the Neon-level projects now contained only source files and nothing else, Neon no longer perceived a need to "upgrade" those projects. Now when I re-open a "Neon-pure" project, that project's folders have retained the expansion levels they had when I closed that project.

Another pleasant by-product of performing the preceding steps was that I also fixed a problem wherein **Window** -> **Show View** -> **Other** displayed a long list of red icons under **org.eclipse.e4.secondaryDataStack**:

[image: Eclipse org.eclipse.e4.secondaryDataStack errors]

Those red icons no longer appear.

Hope this helps...